# Why does mutate(row_number()) fail for data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

When I try to use `row_number()` from `dplyr` on a data.table, it throws an error.  Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
mine <- data.table(a = 1:10)
mine %>% mutate(row_number())
# Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
#   argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Convert it to a `tbl_df` and it works, i.e. `mine %>% tbl_df %>% mutate(rn= row_number())`  Why not use the `data.table` methods for `data.table`?  It could be a bug..

Comment: @CactusWoman, I think it is, acutally.

Comment: Seems like a [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/438).

Comment: if you use `data.table`'s, why not `mine[, row_number := .I]`

Comment: @akrun that's a great workaround -- `mine %>% tbl_df() %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% tbl_dt()`.  @Henrik, thanks, I hadn't seen that.  @mtoto, good idea, but I can't figure out how to make that work with grouping.

Comment: `mine[, row_number := 1:.N, by = group]`

Comment: @Jaap Or `mine[, rowid(group)]` in the current devel version (1.9.7).

Answer (score 3):

The `dplyr::row_number()` function has a mandatory parameter, which should be the name of the column that you want to do a row number for.

In your example, you should have written it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
mine <- data.table(a = 1:10) %>% 
    mutate(row_number(a))
```

Because `a` is the name of the column that you want to add the `row_number()` for. Without this, then R throws the error `argument "x" is missing, with no default`.

However, I'd suggest using the `tibble::rowid_to_column()` function. It's cleaner.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
mine <- data.table(a = 1:10) %>% 
    rowid_to_column()
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I guess the dtplyr package should handle this. Could open an issue if it doesn't https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr